# command expansion: how to convince eshell I'm not trying to execute an elisp expression?

Tags: emacs, expansion, eshell

```
git grep fizzbuzz $(git rev-list --all)
fatal: Invalid object name 'Symbol's function definition is void'.
```

Of course, the same command in `M-x shell` works fine.

**How do I convince eshell I'm not trying to execute an elisp expression here so I can get the git grep goodness I so clearly seek?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
git grep fizzbuzz ${git rev-list --all}
```

Answer (score 0):

Works in my emacs if I wrap the $() with backtics, e.g.:

```
git grep fizzbuzz `$(git rev-list --all)`
```